# Best selling item in the month POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need do a query that show me what is best selling item in the month for which month, during the last years. It should be just like this picture.
thank you.

it is just an example

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: show us your table structure + sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want exactly one item, then `distinct on` is the best approach:

```
select distinct on (ano, mes) t.*
from t
order by ano, mes, cantidad desc;
```

In the event of ties, this returns an arbitrary product.

If you want all products with the maximum quantity in each month, use window functions (`rank()` or `dense_rank()`) or more traditional SQL:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.cantidad = (select max(t2.cantidad) from t t2 where t2.ano = t.ano and t2.mes = t.mes);
```